# xaxis.major_label_orientation for bokeh Bar

Tags: python, bokeh

In regular (low level) plotting one can set label orientation like so:

```
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4
```

per http://docs.bokeh.org/en/0.9.3/docs/user_guide/styling.html#tick-label-orientation

I want to set x axis label orientation to 'horizontal' in `bokeh.charts.Bar` and cannot find the way to do this.

Bokeh 0.9.3.

Answer (score 2):

The `bokeh.charts` API was deprecated and removed in 2017, and should not be used for anything at this point.

Since then, Bokeh support for categorical and bar plots in the well-supported `bokeh.plotting` API has gotten immensely better. It is now possible to rotate the axis labels on a bar chart in the standard way:

```
from math import pi
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show

types = list("ABCDE")
values = [10, 20, 50, 25, 35]

p = figure(x_range=types, plot_height=250)
p.vbar(x=types, top=values, width=0.9)

p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = pi/4   # standard styling code

show(p)
```

[image]

You can find more information and examples in the [Handling Categorical Data](http://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/categorical.html) section of the User's Guide.